# Add key and value to Zend MultiCheckbox dynamically

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have retrieved courseList and courseId from databse like this
    foreach ($courses as $item) {
              $checkBoxText = '';
              $checkBoxText .= $item['courseRubric']. "-". $item['courseNumber']. " ". $item['courseTitle']. " [".$item['semester']. " " . $item['year']. "]";

```
           $this->courseList[] = $checkBoxText;

           $checkboxId = '';
           $checkboxId .= $item['id'];
           $this->courseId[] = $checkboxId;

        }
```

Now, I want to add these array items to Zend_MultiCheckbox,
    foreach ($this->courseId as $key => $value) {
            $courseId[$value]= $value;
        }
        foreach ($this->courseList as $key => $value) {

```
         $element->addMultiOptions(array(
            $courseId[$key] => $value

         ));
    }
```

This logic is not working.Can anyone suggest me how I can get
    Course

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1 :

```
foreach ($this->courseList as $key => $value) {
     $element->addMultiOption("$courseId[$key]", "$value");
}
```

2:

```
$opions = array();
foreach ($this->courseList as $key => $value) {
   $options[$courseId[$key]] = $value;
}
$element->addMultiOptions($options);
```

I think, the 2nd is better.

Good luck.